# Returning UI field attributes in server JSON response

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest

Let's say I have multiple form fields to be rendered on the UI. Also, as a standard Modify flow, assume that the fields rendered would have some attributes like value, mandatory, editable, disabled, label, regex (to validate against), etc

While "value" would have to be returned from the service (since it is persisted db value), is it a good practice to also return the other attributes/flags like mandatory, editable, etc from the service which might have some business logic (e.g. the field editable state being true or false is based on some specific workflow status value)
Is it better to avoid anything related to business logic to maintain on the UI V/s the argument that since mandatory, editable, etc are UI specific, they should be maintained on the UI.
Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: UI and Service should be separate. Rather use roles to give access to UI components.

Comment: Roles are there in place...It is just the exchange of info between UI and service...specifically for the field attributes

Comment: I'd say service should not have any idea about UI . For eg. Service should not return whether a field should be shown or not. We should be handling this using Roles and GrantedAuthorities (Authorization in more granular level) . For eg. user is Admin and has authorities VIEW_PHONE , EDIT_PHONE. User is DEV and only has VIEW_PHONE.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks can be transformed into forms and their parameters into input fields or sub-forms. Very complex GUIs can be generated this way, though there will be still logic which does not have anything to do with the service, e.g. on which panel to display which representation, or how are the displayed representations interrelated, etc. This information can be added to the GUI only by the client developers.

The input field flags you mention describe hyperlink parameters, so they are related to hyperlinks rather than the returned data. If there is a form involved think of it as it was auto-filled with the data, instead of thinking on it as a resource representation.

Afaik. the only REST framework which partially implements this is Hydra, but I already sent such a feature request for better support years ago, which was rejected. Still they appear to go to this direction. https://github.com/hypermedia-app/Alcaeus I am writing a similar framework based on RDF technologies, but it won't be open source. So if you need this for a current work, then probably better to do it manually, because developing a framework for it takes a lot of time.